# compiling c++ projects with dlib library on linux

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, dlib

I want to use dlib library for my c++ projects in linux. I have installed it successfully and able to compile and run the .cpp samples  files given under the dlib. I have compiled the sample files through the

"g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -I.. ../dlib/all/source.cpp -lpthread -lX11 example_program_name.cpp" given in [http://dlib.net/compile.html][1]

but I am unable to use the same command to run .cpp files which are the outside dlib-18.18/examples directory

Can someone help me out with compiling c++ file (with dlib library usage) from any user directory in linux?

I came to know that we have to include the path of dlib installation folder while trying to compile it from any other user directory. So I tried the command

" g++ -O3 **-I/home/praneeth/computervision/**.. ../dlib/all/source.cpp -lpthread -lX11 project3_face.cpp -o project_face `pkg-config --cflags opencv` `pkg-config --libs opencv`"

but it gave me the result:
g++: error: ../dlib/all/source.cpp: No such file or directory

**Note:** dlib-18.18 folder is present in my /home/praneeth/computervision/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how correct is this but it got compiled when I ran the command like: `g++ -O3 -I/home/praneeth/computervision/dlib-18.18 /home/praneeth/computervision/dlib-18.18/dlib/all/source.cpp -lpthread -lX11 project3_face.cpp -o project_face pkg-config --cflags opencv pkg-config --libs opencv` any comments on this regarding why this works?

Answer (score 0):

g++ -Wl,-V -std=c++11 -o3 -I/home/user/dlib-19.6 /home/user/dlib-19.6/dlib/all/source.cpp -lpthread -lX11 -o Test Test.cpp `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`

Comment: `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs` must be enclosed by a `